# PhotoImage instance has no attribute 'resize'

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Im geting the error *'PhotoImage instance has no attribute 'resize''* despite multiple online sources stating that this is the way to do resize an image using PIL. Any Ideas?

relevant code:

```
Deathwing = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('Deathwing.PNG'))

Deathwing2=Deathwing.resize((100,50),Image.ANTIALIAS)

picture1=Label(pictures_frame,image=Deathwing2)

picture1.grid(column=1,row=1)
```

and PIL is impoted as:

```
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
```

Answer (score 9):

For anyone who has the same problem I fixed it by doing:

```
 deathwing=Image.open('Deathwing.PNG')
 image2=deathwing.resize((100,50),Image.ANTIALIAS)
 Deathwing2=ImageTk.PhotoImage(image2)
```